# AWS APIGateway - Cors error on python lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

When I hit my lambda endpoint from postman I am able to successfully trigger the lambda but from my react app using fetch I get a CORs error.

Using CDK I have allowed my Domain.

**cdk restapi config**

```
defaultCorsPreflightOptions:{
        allowOrigins: ["https://example.com"],
        allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS,
        allowHeaders: Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS
      }
```

**lambda.py**

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions

def handle_request(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    try:
        email_client.send_email(
            Source=CONFIGURATION.from_email,
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': CONFIGURATION.to_emails
            },
            Message={
                'Subject': {
                    'Data': 'Form Submission'
                },
                'Body': {
                    'Html': {
                        'Data': build_email_body(body)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        res = {
            'headers': {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "{\"result\": \"Success.\"}"
        }
     
        return res
```

Comment: Are you sending requests from localhost ?

Comment: No from a a hosted site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a formatting error in the code rather than anything to do with CORs. Checking format here can help to locate the problem https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier