# CORS Error using AWS Lambda (SAM) and React

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am preparing a simple React application that needs to do some POST requests via axios against AWS Lambda. I created the Lambda API and Function via [SAM][1]. I followed AWS [documentation][2] to get this set up. So far, the API is functional using Postman and results are as expected. However, when running on React I get a CORS error. When I deploy to Lightsail, I see the same CORS error. I tried using this [reference][3] to debug, but was not successful. I have been at this for over 24 hours, and was hoping a fresh perspective might see where I am going wrong. I listed the lambda file, the template, and error below:

##### template.yml:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  openai-site-parser-and-summary

  Sample SAM Template for openai-site-parser-and-summary

Globals:
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
  Function:
    Timeout: 120
    LoggingConfig:
      LogFormat: JSON

Resources:
  MyApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowCredentials: "'*'"
        AllowMethods: "'*'"

  OpenAiSiteParserFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          MY_API_KEY: "MY_API-KEY"
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.10
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        EndpointEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway
            Path: /parse
            Method: post

  MyApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - MyApiGateway
      - OpenAiSiteParserFunction
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway

  MyApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    Properties:
      Enabled: true

  MyUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    DependsOn:
      - MyApiGatewayDeployment
    Properties:
      ApiStages:
        - ApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway
          Stage: Prod
      Description: Usage plan for My API
      UsagePlanName: MyUsagePlan
      Throttle:
        BurstLimit: 100
        RateLimit: 50
      Quota:
        Limit: 10000
        Period: MONTH

  MyUsagePlanKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey
    Properties:
      KeyId: !Ref MyApiKey
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: !Ref MyUsagePlan

Outputs:
  OpenAiSiteParserApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${MyApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/parse/"
  OpenAiSiteParserFunction:
    Description: "Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt OpenAiSiteParserFunction.Arn
  OpenAiSiteParserFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for function"
    Value: !GetAtt OpenAiSiteParserFunctionRole.Arn
```

##### app.py:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from openai import OpenAI



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Logic...

    return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : True
            },
            "body": json.dumps({
                "summary": final_summary
            })
        }
```

##### Error in React:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://1234567890.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/parse/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

### Edits:

##### Resolution Attempt #1:

Thanks for the feedback, I made the changes suggested to the following items:

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
# Logic...

return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
            "summary": final_summary
        })
    }
```

```
I also checked Chrome -> Network:

preflight:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Content-Length:
3
Content-Type:
application/json
Date:
Tue, 19 Dec 2023 22:59:25 GMT
Via:
1.1 1234567890.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Apigw-Id:
QNn8HGBZiYcEpTA=
X-Amz-Cf-Id:
aV_aaCl7m0ArqnQSOaVwk9w==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop:
BOS50-C3
X-Amzn-Requestid:
6c3bf257-4f6b-48a8-f03b21b3c31f
X-Cache:
Miss from cloudfront

post:
Content-Length:
36
Content-Type:
application/json
Date:
Tue, 19 Dec 2023 22:59:26 GMT
Via:
1.1 1234567890.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Apigw-Id:
QNn8IF6VCYcEstQ=
X-Amz-Cf-Id:
nhIp3EOY3jU8aq0KB28w==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop:
BOS50-C3
X-Amzn-Errortype:
InternalServerErrorException
X-Amzn-Requestid:
9643e1b3-4f7e-4c03-429b598e13a5
X-Cache:
Error from cloudfront









  [1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html
  [2]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-corsconfiguration.html
  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716391/aws-apigateway-cors-error-on-python-lambda
```

Comment: In your browser's Dev Tools >> NETWORK, see what the headers are for the "preflight" OPTIONS request to your API. Is your above `lambda_handler` being invoked by the OPTIONS call, which is what a browser calls prior to making `fetch()` or `axios()` call, to validate that the page the browser is making the API call from is okay according to the server (CORS is a way that the browser protects itself from calling, say, a bank's APIs from a spoofed web page...so the bank's server is saying "it is okay to call my APIs from the following servers...."). Is your lambda telling the browser it is okay?

Comment: You cannot use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. That is an invalid combination

Comment: @GregFenton I checked Network and added the observations above. I am seeing a status 200 for the preflight, and 502 from post. I checked API gateway, and I see this there as well. I cannot however enable CORS on post for some reason, neither automatically via SAM or manually.

Comment: CORS is NOT a server issue....it is a BROWSER issue.  The server's preflight response (its headers) tell the browser which sites are safe to call the API from.  This stops someone from spoofing a bank's web page.  The bank's API server would say "only call me from https://mybank.bankco.com/" (or wherever) and if the browser loaded "https://myfakebank.com" and sent the preflight to the actual bank's server, the BROWSER would refuse to make the API call (the browser will throw a CORS error). So check the preflight's HEADERS to see if the web page your API call is being made from is "allowed".